# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getElementsByClassName')

Tags: javascript, axios, веб-скрейпинг

Делаю проект по парсингу сайта Афиши спб через запросы Axios, но в процессе перебора классов на одном из getElementsByClassName выскакивает ошибка, о том, что элемент undefined

```
var event = response.data;
          const dom = new JSDOM(event);
          try {
              var relLink = dom.window.document.getElementById('root')!.getElementsByClassName('eIEvy')[0].getElementsByClassName('zg08I FMkqG')[0].getElementsByClassName('nr7ax')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getElementsByClassName('zg08I GkNup')[0].getElementsByTagName('section')[0].getElementsByClassName('yD3VJ')[0].getElementsByClassName('AkpFh')[0].getElementsByClassName('GgiYd.vscmH')[0].getElementsByClassName('OILfh')[0].getElementsByClassName('uAK3W')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].outerHTML;
              var newLink = relLink.replace('/', 'https://www.afisha.ru/');
              console.log(newLink);
          }
```

Значение undefined принимает на классе 'AkpFh'

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getElementsByClassName')
at C:\Users\anato\Desktop\untitled3\pars.js:19:357
```

Не могу понять, в чем заключается ошибка, ибо путь верный (ссылка на страницу парсинга - "https://www.afisha.ru/search/?query=%D0%94%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B0"

Comment: `dom.window.document.getElementById('root')!` - очевидно возвращает `undefined` а значит элемента с таким `id` нет. Либо один из `getElementsByClassName` или `getElementsByTagName` возвращает пустую коллекцию

Comment: Элемента с классом `AkpFh` нет, а тут указан некорректный селектор: `getElementsByClassName('GgiYd.vscmH')`